# 'cordova-plugin-play-games-service' is not in the npm registry

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using ionic 4 and trying to install Google Play Games Services according to the documentation. However, when I type the following command:

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-play-games-service  --variable APP_ID="XXXX"

I get the following error message:

cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:

npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not found : cordova-plugin-play-games-service

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404  'cordova-plugin-play-games-service' is not in the npm registry.

npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Could you please let me know how to solve this issue and install the plugin?

Thanks,

Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the 's' in service,

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-play-games-services --variable
>   APP_ID=you_app_id_here

doc https://github.com/artberri/cordova-plugin-play-games-services

Comment: Thank you very much Sergio, looks like the ionic 4 docs have a typo.